# Gradle build tools 1.5.0 excludes .so files

Tags: android, gradle, shared-libraries, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm working with a library that depends on a shared object file ex. libName.so and in the past I've simply packaged the libName.so file with my jar that I've distributed. Now by updating the gradle version from 1.3.1 to 1.5.0,

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' // 1.3.1 -> 1.5.0
```

these .so files in my library are no longer added to the app's .apk file that my library in the app depends on. For the library (ex. a jar), it doesn't seem to matter whether the .so files are in the assets, libs, or jniLibs folder.

Extracting the apk generated with my dependency referenced:

ex.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.x:library_with_folder_containing_so_files:version'
}
```

Before (Gradle 1.3.1)
[image: Gradle v1.3.1]

After (Gradle 1.5.0)
[image: Gradle v1.5.0]

It seems that if you have files that aren't shared objects, they won't be removed when the APK is generated. Was wondering if v1.5.0 has a new policy I can't seem to find or if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this problem don't load native libraries from the assets folder. Instead if you add your libraries to another folder called lib with the same folder structure, gradle builds will not remove the native libraries.

Ex. new jar file structure

```
lib
    - armeabi
        - libLibraryName.so
    - x86
        - libLibraryName.so
    - mips
        - libLibraryName.so
```

Should your native libraries be packaged in your jar file this way you should also be able to call System.loadLibrary("LibraryName").